# XPath - not match element with certain ancestor

Tags: html, xpath

I would like to count the text of all descendant elements which do not have a link as an ancestor.

```
//*[string-length(normalize-space(//*[not(ancestor::a)])) > 10]
```

Which if tested on this structure would return `[Get This Text]`

```
<b>
   ignore
   <a>ignore</a>
   Get This Text
</b>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you mean by "count the text" but the following expression returns all elements that don't have a link as ancestor and whose normalized string value is longer than 10 characters:

```
//*[not(ancestor::a) and string-length(normalize-space()) > 10]
```

Since you want the expression to return the string `'Get this text'`, maybe you want select text nodes, not elements:

```
//text()[not(ancestor::a) and string-length(normalize-space()) > 10]
```